# How does a quantum computer find the correct password faster than classical computers using brute-force?

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, ibm-q-experience

I didn't get this part right! For example, we have an online box with a 16-digit password, and we don't know what the password is! How can a quantum computer find the correct password faster than classical computers knowing that numbers are chosen at random? this makes both computers have 50/50 chance to guess the correct password if you are lucky enough right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In the setting you described we cannot use a Quantum Computer to benefit us. But if we are able to somehow perform the password check itself within a quantum computer, then [Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) gives us a real advantage. For example, if we're trying to find the correct hash for a Blockchain.

In your scenario, the password-checking is being done by a remote server, and indeed we cannot do much; but if we got hold of the hashed passwords + salt on the server and we know the hashing algorithm, then again we can use a quantum computer to speed up finding the actual passwords.

Comment: so what you trying to say is if we know the algorithm of how the password generates, we have a high chance to generate the right password?

Comment: @ZakariaHalloumi you also need to know the final hash, in order to test whether the password is correct

Comment: @ZakariaHalloumi, what we need to have is the explicit password-checking algorithm. Usually passwords are not stored directly, but hashed (with additional data called "salt"), so to check a password we need to have this hash value.